# Как отключить процесс через PuTTY

Tags: python, flask, putty, winscp

Есть проект на Flask, арендовал VDS сервер для учёбы. И появилась совсем не критичная проблема. Закинул я проект flask на сервер используя WinSCP и PuTTY. Запустил его предварительно создав для него виртуальную среду. Запустил на порту :5000. Когда закрывал PuTTY, забыл прожать кнопки Ctrl+C чтобы остановить проект Flask. Теперь я не могу использовать этот порт. Проблема не критичная, но я не хочу в каждом проекте Flask теперь задавать Порт.

Answer (score 2):

В Putty сначала определи номер процесса

```
lsof -i tcp:5000
```

а потом убей его ( замени 36440 на своё значение из результата выполнения строки выше)

```
sudo kill 36440
```

WinSCP - это файловый менеджер, в нём не получится выполнить команды.

Comment: забыл упомянуть. Включал через uWSGI, и теперь не отключается. kill тупо ничего не делает

Comment: номер процесса определился? Убивайте так: sudo kill -KILL 39449
или sudo kill -9 39449

Comment: kill -9 помог, спасибо огромное)